# Construcción de consulta en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera hacer esta consulta con Eloquent de laravel, el tema es que la consulta es de una tabla recursiva, pero tiene un ordenamiento en base a una columna, es decir si la columna "ordena" tiene 0 ordena por id y si la columna "ordena" tiene 1 ordena por nombre

```
SELECT a.id as codigo, a.nombre as nombre 
FROM catalogos a 
JOIN catalogos b ON b.id = a.catalogo_id 
ORDER BY IF(a.ordenado = '0', a.codigo, a.nombre)
```

¿Cómo lo haría en eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

```
$resultado = Catalogo::select('a.id as codigo', 'a.nombre as nombre')
                     ->join('catalogos b',  'b.id', =, 'a.catalogo_id')               
                     ->orderByRaw('IF(a.ordenado = 0, a.codigo, a.nombre)')
                     ->get();
```

Prueba de este modo

- Usa el método `join` para ejecutar el `inner join`
- Usa `select` para indicar las columnas
- Usa `orderByRaw` para indicar la condición lógica de ordenamiento